# How to add new tags to an AWS S3 Bucket using Boto3 if the existing tags on the bucket contains 'aws:' prefixes, without deleting existing tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am appending new tag to S3 buckets tag set without deleting existing tags But if my bucket contains 'aws:' as prefix, it gives the following error: 'An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateTags operation: Value ( aws:cloudformation:stack-name ) for parameter key is invalid. Tag keys starting with 'aws:' are reserved for internal use.'

How to add new tags without deleting the existing tags in this case using boto3?

Answer (score 0):

Tag names starting by ‘aws:’ are reserved for AWS internal usage. You can use any other name for your tag.

See the following doc for restrictions on tag names.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/allocation-tag-restrictions.html

Comment: I am not adding tag with prefix 'aws', These are the tags added already I am appending my new tag 'owner' to the list of existing tags when I get this error

Comment: Can you give the exact CLI you are using to add the Tag ? Also how many tags are already set on that bucket ? Objects can have maximum 50 tags.

Comment: I am using the below code: 

bucket_tagging = s3_resoure.BucketTagging(BucketName)
response = s3_client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=BucketName)
tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
tags.append({'Key': CONST.NON_COMPLIANT_DATE_TAG_KEY, 'Value': str(now)})
Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet': tags})

There are only 2 existing tags on that bucket